# Question about using SelectedTab

Tags: c#, tabs, controls

I am creating an app that uses tabs. I want to be able to add, edit, and delete on each tab. I have these three buttons outside of the tabs so they can be used for each one. I am trying to figure out how to use SelectedTab so that the tab I am currently on will be the one that gets changed. Any help is appreciated. thanks

Comment: What do you want to add/delete/add? Do you have some controls on the current tab that you want to work with?

Comment: Basically, all i want to do add, edit, and delete from the sql database that I am connected to. And then have those changes show up in the datagrid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using buttons, I let users double click on the datagrid and a new window where they can edit and such.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this in your buttons' event handlers:

```
        if (tabControl1.SelectedTab == tabPage1) 
        { 
            /* do something */ 
        }
        else if (tabControl1.SelectedTab == tabPage2)
        {
            /* do something else */
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the currently selected tab by using `TabControl.SelectedTab` property. Once you got the selected tab, you can make appropriate changes in selected tab.

Answer (score 0):

For delete, put this in the event handler of the delete button:

```
tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tabControl1.SelectedTab);
```

For add, use this:

```
var newTabPage = new TabPage("Tab Name");
tabControl1.TabPages.Add(myTabPage);
```

Comment: Sorry, i was a little unclear, I dont want to add new tabs, but add items to the datagrid on a particular tab.

Comment: Based on the recent question comments, I think I misunderstood your requirements. I'll leave this answer up just in case though.